# Kendoui scheduler different time

Tags: kendo-ui, timezone, kendo-scheduler

Scheduler showing starttime and endtime as in the database. 
The problem: for example, when i creating or updating event to "start time = 10:00" and "end time = 11:00" then scheduler saving in db "start time = 06:00" and "end time = 07:00".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a timezone issue.  You can keep the time in utc on server and client - kendo will adjust it on client side.

see:
http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides

Comment: Ty for help, i solved my problem. I changed the code in API.

$date_s = $request->models[0]->date_s;
$date_sw =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+0 hours", strtotime($date_s)));
 $sql = "UPDATE `records` SET `date_s`='$date_sw', `date_e`='$date_ew'  WHERE id_record= $id_record";

IDK how it works.